# Is there a way to select and apply styling to a scrollable element that its scrollbar thumb is being hovered?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a React component named Scrollable which only wraps the element which should be scrollable and applies some custom styles to scrollbar. Scrollbar thumb has `background-color: inehrit;` property set to inherit background color from the wrapper element because by default `::--webkit-scrollbar-thumb` pseudo element doesn't support `transition` property to have transitions between `background-color` property changes. To support transitions I apply `background-color` changes to wrapper and `::--webkit-scrollbar-thumb` simply inherits the backgroudn color on wrapper with transition applied. Scrollbar is by default is hidden by its parent/wrapper having `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` property. When scrollable element is being hovered I change it's background-color property to `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)` so the thumb changes color with transition when scrollable element is being hovered, thus being visible. When user is not hovering anymore on scrollable element I revert the background-color with transition-delay set, so scrollbar thumb gets invisible after the specified delay when user moves the mouse out of the scrollable element. To apply these customisations I apply the following styling to my Scrollable component:

##### Scrollable component

```js
// components/Scrollable/index.js

import './style.css';

const Scrollable = props => {
    const {
        className: customClassName,
        children
    } = props;

    let className = 'scrollable-inner bg-card';

    if(customClassName) {
        className = `${className} ${customClassName}`;
    }

    return (
        <div
            className="scrollable"
        >
            <div className={className}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Scrollable;
```

##### Global scrollbar and scrollable component stylings

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .75rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: inherit;
}

.scrollable {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.scrollable:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.scrollable:not(:hover) {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

.scrollable-inner {

}
```

##### Working simplified code

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .75rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: inherit;
}

.scrollable {
    max-height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.scrollable:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.scrollable:not(:hover) {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

.scrollable-inner {

}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-card {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.content {
  height: 1600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">  
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-inner bg-card">
      <p class="content">
        Some long content that is overflowing
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

---

##### Main goal

I want to apply styles to my scrollable element when the scrollable element's scrollbar thumb (`.scrollable::--webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover`) is being hovered. The selector I provided between parantheses only select and apply the scrollable element's scrollbar thumb itself, I want to select and apply styling on the scrollable element itself when its scrollbar thumb is being hovered.

I tried to use `.scrollable:has(::--webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover)` selector but even if it's succesful to apply styles to a parent element when it has a specified children, this selector isn't able to detect if scrollable element has a scrollbar thumb which is being hovered. Thus it fails.

Is there any way to accomplish this with only using CSS or do I have to create a scrollbar element which contains scrollbar track, thumb and other scrollbar elements and override default browser scrollbar?